# select rows where a the column (null ,3,5)

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a problem when selecting a table where I want it to take from a column x conditionals (null,2,3,4)

```
select  * 
from pr_premios_t 
where fecha_PAGO BETWEEN '01-OCT-2021' AND '11-ABR-2022' 
    AND COD_PRODUCTO = 16,'is Null'
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't write dates like `01-OCT-2021`. They have to be written like `2021-10-01`

Answer (score 0):

You don't put `is null` in quotes. Use

```
AND (COD_PRODUCTO = 16 OR COD_PRODUCTO IS NULL)
```